# Consider defining a bean of type 'Mapper' in your configuration [Spring-Boot]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

mapstruct doesn't work on my Spring Boot project.

I added dependencies, path, Mapper annotations (componentModel="spring") in the mapper interface and still get the same error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHTPo.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvxo4.png

Answer (score 0):

CategoryMapper is a Entity? if it is kindly add this @NoArgsConstructor becoause its looking for empty constructor

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CategoryMapper {

    
}
```

if you dont have lombok just add this

```
//empty constructor
public CategoryMapper() {

}
```

If this class is Repository make sure to hava @Mapper

```
@Mapper
public class CategoryMapper {

    
}
```

Dont forget also do add this to SpringApplication runner class. This class is generated when you first created the project file

```
@Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

//For repsitory dont forget this.
//This will be added upper of the class in springapplication class runner

@MappedTypes({YourEntity.class})
@MapperScan("package patch to you repository")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the interface Code @SpicySandwich

`@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SubredditMapper {

```
@Mapping(target = "numberOfPosts", expression = "java(mapPosts(subreddit.getPosts()))")
SubredditDto mapSubredditToDto(Subreddit subreddit);

default Integer mapPosts(List<Post> numberOfPosts) {
    return numberOfPosts.size();
}

@InheritInverseConfiguration
@Mapping(target = "posts", ignore = true)
Subreddit mapDtoToSubreddit(SubredditDto subredditDto);
```

}`

Comment: Please update your questing, this is not an answer